# TypeError: accept missing 2 required arguments (Still functional)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

This is a curiosity question.  I have a block of code that executes upon an accepted.connect().
It throws out this error but when I check the results they still work.  And from what I understand from button box: upon pressing OK or cancel, the dialog should close on it's own.  I haven't even initialized self.buttonBox.canceled.connect but when I push cancel the window closes.  When I push OK though the window stays open and gives the following error:

```
TypeError: accept() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'player' and 'window'
```

So here's some code:

```
class UIinit(QtGui.QDialog, UI.Buy_Cargo.Ui_Dialog):
        """The Dialog for initiation"""
        def __init__(self, player, window):
            super(UIinit, self).__init__()
            self.window = window
            self.player = player
            self.setupUi(self)
            #for i in Config.port_prices:
            #   up = getattr(self, "btn_" + i + "_up")
            #    up.clicked.connect(partial(self.up, i, player))
            #    down = getattr(self, "btn_" + i + "_down")
            #    down.clicked.connect(partial(self.down, i))
            #    add_price = getattr(self, "H_" + i)
            #    add_price.setText(i +
            #        " (" + str(self.player.port.price[i]) + ")")
            self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(  # the important part
                partial(self.accept, player, window))
        def accept(self, player, window):
            if int(self.V_Total.text()) <= player.money:
                for i in player.ship.cargo:
                    num = int(getattr(self, "V_" + i).text())
                    player.ship.cargo[i] += num
                window.to_shipyard()
dia = UIinit(player, window)
dia.exec_()
```

I've tried connect(lambda: self.accept(player, window)) and using self.player and self.window as the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it has to do with me overwriting the dialog's accept function.  Once I changed the accept() to GoNinjaGoNinjaGo() everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

This simplified snippets below does work as expected, so your problem is elsewhere. Just a wildguess - if you copy/pasted you code, there are tabs in it and if you have a mix of tabs and spaces you can get really weird results - like having `def accept` actually being defined in `__init__` itself instead of being a proper method, in which case `self` is not automagically passed to the function. Doesn't really match your error message but that might be worth checking....

```
from functools import partial

class Button(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.callbacks = []
    def connect(self, callback):
        self.callbacks.append(callback)
    def click(self):
        for callback in self.callbacks:
            callback()

class UI(object):
    """The Dialog for initiation"""
    def __init__(self, player, window):
        self.window = window
        self.player = player
        self.button = Button()
        self.button.connect(  # the important part
            partial(self.accept, player, window))
        self.button.connect( 
            lambda: self.accept(player, window))

    def accept(self, player, window):
        print "accept %s %s" % (player, window)

    def exec_(self):
        self.button.click()
player = "p"
window = "w"
dia = UI(player, window)
dia.exec_()
```