# builtins.TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'height' and 'radius'

Tags: python

I am getting an error that says I am missing 2 required positional arguments: 'height' and 'radius.' I feel like I have tried everything but I know I am missing something small. Any help? 
Thanks

```
# import math
import math

class SodaCan :
    # Constructs sodaCan with a given height and radius
    # @param height = given height and radius = given radius
    def __init__(self, height, radius):
        self._height = height
        self._radius = radius

    # Constructs the volume with the given height and radius
    def volume(self):
        self._volume = (pi * (self._radius ** 2) * self._height)

    # Constructs the Surface Area with the given height and radius
    def surfaceArea(self):
        self._surfaceArea = (2 * pi * self._radius * self._height) + (2 * pi   * (self._radius)**2)

    # Return the volume
    def getVolume(self):
        return self._volume

    # Return the Surface Area
    def getSurfaceArea(self):
        return self._surfaceArea
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Below there is the test program for my code.

```
## 
# This program test the sodaCan.py
##

# import math so the program can read pi
import math

# from the file folder, ipmort the code from program 'sodaCan'
from sodaCan import SodaCan

mySodaCan = SodaCan()
mySodaCan.height(10)
mySodaCan.radius(4)

print(mySodaCan.getVolume())
print(mySodaCan.getSurfaceArea())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: accept missing 2 required arguments (Still functional)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380276/typeerror-accept-missing-2-required-arguments-still-functional)

Comment: Can you show how you're calling SodaCan (i.e. are you doing x = SodaCan(5,4) ?)  (If your possible duplicate is correct, they you also need to show more code.)

Answer (score 2):

When you define the initializer like this:

```
class SodaCan:

    def __init__(self, height, radius):
        ...
```

You are saying that height and radius are *required*.  They must be specified in order to create a soda can instance.

```
mySodaCan = SodaCan(height=10, radius=4)
```

If you want them to be optional, you may specify default values for those arguments when you define the `__init__` method.  Then when you create an instance, the arguments will take the default values if omitted when creating an instance.

Comment: @MakieMichaux yes, it seems you have *multiple* errors. The message is pretty revealing too, `self._volume` is not defined. I urge you to think about why this is the case instead of getting people here to debug your code for you piece by piece (which isn't what this site is designed for).

Answer (score 2):

You need the pass the height and radius when you initialize the class. Arguments in the init class mean that they have to be passed when you initialize the class. Something like this would work:

```
height = 40
radius = 10
a = SodaCan(height, radius)
```